# Gitignore file does not ignore

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I´m writing on a protject and work with a Google Api Key. I want to ignore the file where the key is stored, that nobody can see it. But it doesnt work. I found no question, that answers my question.

I added this code to my .gitignore file:

```
# Google Api Key
/GoogleService-Info.plist
```

But the fle is not ignored. I thought that now every file with this name have to be ignored. What´s the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

you have to delete the file if it's already committed;
Gitignore gives you the capability to not track specified files on it.

Comment: you can mark the answer as accepted, so others can benefit from it. This is how StackOverflow works ;)